# Calculating Svg <g> tag width

Tags: matrix, svg, svgpanzoom

I am new to SVG. I have a svg image, i have applied a transform matrix for a `<g>` tag. Now I want to calculate `<g>` tag width and height. on page load i can calculate width and height using getBBox() or getBoundingClientRec() functions. But when i am resizing the window i am changing matrix values,  Before updating matrix values how can i calculate `<g>` tag width and height.

-- getBBox() and getBoundingClientRec() returns width and height based on matrix values.

example:
On page load:

```
<g id="xyz" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,10,10)"></g>
```

When resizing the window i am calling a method which calculates matrix values.
**Note: Matrix values are calculated not yet updated**
I need to center the image to the browser window on resizing. I am subtracting window width and image width divided by 2 and i am applying that value for matrix.e i., "x"  value. 
example: new matrix values are [1.2,0,0,1.2,x,10]

For centering map i need to know  width and height of `<g>` by using calculated matrix values i.e., [1.2,0,0,1.2,x,10]

Comment: why not apply the matrix and then get the information you need?

Comment: I have updated my question can you please check it.

Comment: Add a viewBox to the SVG and you won't need to do all that messing about.

Comment: I have viewBox on resizing i need to make my image fit in the visible browser window with the hep of transformation matrix

Comment: Sounds like something you shouldn't have to do if you write the SVG correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the transformed group with another `<g`> and call `getBBox()` on that.

However why not describe the original problem you are trying to achieve? Since you are new to SVG, there is a chance you are approaching your problem the wrong way. Maybe we can suggest a better solution than trying to manipulate matrixes yourself.

Comment: Paul thanks for your suggestion. I will explain my problem in short. I need to fit svg image on resizing window and center it. I am using svg-pan-zoom.js. And i am customizing it. On resizing i need to calculate matrix values to center it and fit in window. For centering i need to know svg <g> width

Comment: Well, you probably want to modify the svg-pan-zoom code to have it work properly. First I would suggest you add your support to this bug report, so it gets fixed more quickly: https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom/issues/185.